# Logout function in Django not working as Expected

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-authentication, django-auth-models

**I have not used any middleware, when i click on logout button on my Home Page template, the logout function execute without any error.but when i go back to main page without jumping to login page.. i see myself as logged in user**

*here is my authentiCation/views.py*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import request,HttpResponseRedirect
# for user creation & login form
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
# for user related Queries
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# imports for test purpose
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.

# register page 
def register_Page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form= UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username= request.POST['username']
            password= request.POST['password1']
            user= authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
            login(request,user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Either the user name is not available or you may have filled the form incorrectly')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
        context= {'form':form}
        return render(request,'authentication/register_Page.html',context)

# login page
def login_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username= request.POST['username']
        password= request.POST['password']
        # returns user if credentials are valid
        user= authenticate(request, username=username, password= password)
        # check if user var contains the user
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid credentials')

    return render(request,'authentication/login.html')

# logout Page
def log_out(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('logout_page')
```

*authentiCation/urls.py*

```
from django.urls import path
from authentiCation import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('register/',views.register_Page),
    path('login/',views.login_page,name='login_page'),
    path('logout/',views.log_out),
]
```

**Main App Files**
*urls*

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('App_wfi_Community.urls')),
    path('Ask/',include('askQuestion.urls')),
    path('auth/',include('authentiCation.urls')),
]
```

*Home.html*

```
{% extends "basic.html" %}
{% load humanize %}
{% block title %}WFI-Community{% endblock title %}
{% block body %}

<!--  search button   -->
<h5>Welcome {{username}},<h5> <!--  I see my username here   -->
<form action="/search" method="get">
<div class="container py-3 row">
  <div class="col-md-8 offset-2">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input name="searchfieldText" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit">Search</button>
      <span><a href="{% url 'login_page' %}">Logout</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
<!--  and some more HTML stuff which is irrelavent here -->
```

Comment: How do you know that clicking the Logout link executes the logout function? The link is to login_page.

Comment: @BradMartsberger actually i forgot that.. now i have corrected this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give a name to this eg
path('logout/',views.log_out, name="logout" ) and change it in the home.html.
eg "{% url 'logout' %}">Logout

Comment: thats worked prefectly, but now the problem is the urls are keeps on appending like this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout/login_page`

Comment: but i want url like this =>    for logout page= `http://127.0.0.1:8000/logout`  for login page= `http://127.0.0.1:8000/login_page`

Comment: That is the only way. It has to be that way.

Comment: Accept as an answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: but what i do for urls.. i am beginner and dont know how to handle this..

Comment: Now I figured it out myself by using reverse in the views.py file . reverse handled the appending urls very nicely and now the code is working as expected.. in b/w, thanks @fakeMake for helping out.